# R: print list object by name that appears more than once

Tags: r

Hi suppose I have the following:

```
a <- list (a=55, a=66, c=100)
```

What I want to do is print only objects that is named a? 
however when I do this, `print (a$a)` it will just print the first object 55, 
I also tried looping through like a$a but that did not work as well.

```
for (b in a$a ){
  print (b[1])
}
```

I could try to loop and do some sort of string comparison with the name but I'm planning to work this through a huge list in the 100's MB + so would like to avoid this.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to print all the `list` elements that have name 'a', then create a logical vector with `==` and subset the `list`

```
a[names(a) == 'a']
```